# AngularModalService: passing data to controller

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

Not getting much w/ the search.  I found one kinda similar thread here but it didn't quite work for me.

The examples show that the Modal will get a separate controller.  Looks something like this.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize','angularModalService']);
app.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.showAlert = function() {

        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: "alertWindow.html",
            controller: "AlertController",
            inputs: {
                title: "Add New Alert",
            }
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                $scope.result = "blah";
            });
        });

     });
}]);

app.controller('AlertController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.close = function(result) {
        close(result, 500); 
    };
}]);
```

The caveat I have is that I want the modal dialog to have some default values which are in SampleController.  I read up on Services but I don't think that works here.  inputs: { } in showModal() looks suspect, but I'm not exactly sure where to get it from once the modal window is shown.  The other examples I've seen just bring up simple yes/no buttons or text inputs w/ empty default values.

Comment: First of all, it looks like you're having syntax errors. You're missing a closing square bracket ']' when you're defining your controllers. Also, your $scope.showAlert is not inside of your SampleController.

Comment: You're right -- thanks for the heads up.  Edited.  However, that was just when I was editing it in the window for legibility, as there is definitely more going on in the controllers than needs to be visible here.  So, my problem still stands.  At least the code should be easier to read now.

Comment: You're not including your ModalService dependency in SampleController. Do you have ModalService defined anywhere?

Comment: I do.  Sorry about that (edited, again).  To point a bit more directly to the problem, from https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service, I see "inputs: A set of values to pass as inputs to the controller. Each value provided is injected into the controller constructor.".  Just not sure how to reference them after they're injected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs, you inject the inputs into the modal controller. Since title is the input you mentioned above, you would change your modal controller to:

```
app.controller('AlertController', ['$scope', 'title', function($scope, title) {
    $scope.title = title;

    $scope.close = function(result) {
        close(result, 500); 
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks.  Sorry it took me so long to get back to it.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me. How about passing back this title to SampleController ? Anyone please help me on this.